# Any JS/TS IoC containers that allow injecting a collection of all implementing services?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I come from the .NET background and, using Autofac, I found implicit relationship types pretty useful. From Autofac's documentation:

> For example, when Autofac is injecting a constructor parameter of type IEnumerable<ITask> **[(a collection of ITask)]** it will not look for a component that supplies IEnumerable.

> Instead, the container will find all implementations of ITask and inject all of them.

Is there anything similar in the Javascript world, or am I out of luck?

UPD 2022-04-11: I understand the fact that it's impossible to resolve by "type" because there is no type; however, IOC containers in JS work around the absence of types by using "tokens" instead (symbols, strings, etc.)

So what I'm looking for are IoC containers that allow registration of multiple providers under the same token, and then resolving an array of them by the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is a statically typed language, which means types are treated as a first class member. You can easily reference types of your variables at runtime. TypeScript is based on JavaScript, which has no concept of types. At runtime, all types are removed from code, which means there's no way for any code to reference the type. Unfortunately you're SOL.

I use [InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) for dependency injection, it's the most fully featured DI package for JS/TS AFAIK, you can check out the docs to see if it can do something similar (although I doubt it).

EDIT: Inversify has a [multi-inject](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/multi_injection.md) option that'll do what you need.

Comment: Yes, I understand the fact that it's impossible to resolve by "type" because there is no type; however, IOC containers in JS work around the absence of types by using "tokens" instead (symbols, strings, etc.). So my question is still valid! - are there containers that allow registration of multiple providers under the same token, and then resolving an array of them by the token?

Comment: Inversify has a [multi-inject](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/multi_injection.md) option, maybe that's what you're looking for? you'd have to manually bind everything first though.

EDIT: if you're looking to implement Inversify, I suggest going through their [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/tree/master/wiki) for advanced use-cases.

Comment: Exactly, please add it to the answer itself, it is now accepted :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

InversifyJS seems to support what I am looking for through `container.getAll()`.

https://doc.inversify.cloud/en/container_api.html